# Shaka Player - video.ui is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined-reference

I have the following demo page to test Shaka Player for my use case. I'd like to play live content given in an mpd file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/4.3.2/shaka-player.compiled.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/4.3.2/controls.css">
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Salt TV Client</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="header">
<h1 class="display-6 text-center">Salt TV Client</h1>
<hr />
</header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <br>
    <main class="container">
        <h1>Guarda RSI La1 HD</h1>
        <br />

        <div class="ratio ratio-16x9" id="video-container">
      <video controls id="video" playsinline></video>
        </div>

    </main>
    <footer>
<hr />
<div class="container">
<span id="digital-clock"></span>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
const manifestUri = /* My URL */

function initApp() {
      // Install built-in polyfills to patch browser incompatibilities.
      shaka.polyfill.installAll();

      // Check to see if the browser supports the basic APIs Shaka needs.
      if (shaka.Player.isBrowserSupported()) {
        // Everything looks good!
        initPlayer();
      } else {
        // This browser does not have the minimum set of APIs we need.
        console.error('Browser not supported!');
      }
    }

    async function initPlayer() {
      // Create a Player instance.
      const video = document.getElementById('video');
      const player = new shaka.Player(video);

      // Attach player to the window to make it easy to access in the JS console.
      window.player = player;

      // Listen for error events.
      player.addEventListener('error', onErrorEvent);

      // Try to load a manifest.
      // This is an asynchronous process.
      try {
        await player.load(manifestUri);
        await video.play();
        // This runs if the asynchronous load is successful.
        console.log('The video has now been loaded!');
      } catch (e) {
        // onError is executed if the asynchronous load fails.
        onError(e);
      }
    }

    function onErrorEvent(event) {
      // Extract the shaka.util.Error object from the event.
      onError(event.detail);
    }

    function onError(error) {
      // Log the error.
      console.error('Error code', error.code, 'object', error);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initApp);
</script>
</html>
```

When I want to get acces to the ui to configure it, I get video.ui is undefined.

What could the problem be?
Thanks.

I'm expecting the video.ui Object to be defined, so that I can use it to configure the UI of Shaka Player.

Answer (score 0):

Include the link to the UI library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/4.3.5/shaka-player.ui.min.js"></script>
```

and that should fix the issue

note the latest version 4.3.5